# Django csrf Error: CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: django, csrf

I have looked through many other Stack questions regarding this same error, but none of those solutions seem to work for me.

What I am trying to do is have a form that I can take input data and send an email with it.

Here is my code:

```
    #urls.py
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
    from webpage import views

    from django.contrib import admin
    admin.autodiscover()

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^careeropp/','webpage.views.careeropp'),
        url(r'^thanks/','webpage.views.thanks'),
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    )

    #views.py
    from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
    from webpage.forms import ApplyForm
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.core.mail import send_mail
    from django.template import RequestContext
    from django.core.context_processors import csrf
    from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

    @csrf_protect
    def careeropp(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ApplyForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                cd = form.cleaned_data
                send_mail(
                     cd['name'],
                    cd['email'],
                    cd.get('email','emailaddress@gmail.com'),
                    ['email@gmail.com'],
                )
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            form = ApplyForm()
        return render_to_response('webpage/careeropp.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    def thanks(request):
        return render_to_response('webpage/thanks.html')

    #careeropp.html
    <form  enctype="text/plain" method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

I have also checked my settings to make sure csrf was in middleware.

When I load careeropp.html in my browser, I can see the form displayed perfectly. When I go to the page source, the csrf token is there. However, as soon as I press Submit (whether I have filled out the form or not), it redirects to the 403 error: csrf token missing or incorrect.

I am new to web development and Django, so hopefully I didn't make a stupid mistake and someone can help.

Comment: is 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' in your middlewares?

Comment: Have you tried switching enctype="text/plain" to enctype="multipart/form-data" ?

Comment: Ah, thank you! That worked, I now have a different error :P But I think it has to do with setting up django mail, so I'll look into that now.

Comment: Post the answer to help another users.